# Book on Convergence Concepts in Probability without Measure Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, book-recommendation

I am looking for a comprehensive book on Probability which discusses Convergence of Random Variables in detail, excluding portions of Measure Theory. Allan Gut's "Probability: A Graduate Course" seems fabulous, but it has way too much content on Measure Theory, which I do not know at all.

There is a wealth of professors and undergrad students of Stats and Maths on this website; and I would like to directly ask you: which book should suit my situation? Because I CAN learn Measure Theory but considering I am only a first year undergrad, and Measure Theory will be taught to me three years later, I suppose it will only be a wastage of time.

Answer (score 0):

> Grimmett and Stirzaker's Probability and Random Processes fits the
>   bill:
>
> [http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Random-Processes-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572220](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198572220)
>
> It covers everything up to stochastic calculus without measure theory.

[Alex R.](https://mathoverflow.net/users/934/alex-r)